# In $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$: Simultaneous distance reduction to points in $A$ possible iff outside closed convex hull spanned by $A$

Tags: optimization, convex-hulls

I'm working on a problem, and have managed to reduce it to this proposition:

Consider $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ with the following distance function that has $\infty$ as a possible value: $d(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (x_i-y_i)^2$. Given a set of points $A$ all of which are within finite distance of each other, say that a point $y$ dominates $x$ if for all points $a\in A$, the distance between $a$ and $y$ is smaller than that between $a$ and $x$. Also, say that a point is dominated if there is a point that dominates it. A point is dominated iff it does not belong to the closure of the convex hull spanned by $A$.

I think this is true and I also suppose that it exists as a theorem in the literature to which I can refer; or, failing that, that is a fairly simple corollary of such a theorem. However, I have not been able to find it - perhaps because I don't know the right search terms. Can anyone please help?

Comment: @Brian By shifting $A$ to $A-a$ for some $a\in A$, we are entirely in $\ell^2$, as points with infinite distance do not play a role.

Comment: @Casper I've posted an answer and deleted my previous comments since they're now redundant.  The steps that I've not shown in that answerare all basic properties of the real inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$, so you should try to fill in the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the statement is true when $A=\emptyset$, but also we find weird statements like "$x$ dominates $x$", which I'd like to avoid, are actually true in this case, so assume $A \neq \emptyset$.

By replacing $A$ with $A-a$ for some $a \in A$, we may assume $A \subseteq \ell^2(\mathbb{R})$.  Then the closed convex hull $\overline{\mathrm{co}}(A)$ is also a subset of $\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$ and every point of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}\setminus \ell^2(\mathbb{R})$ is dominated by any point of $\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$.  This allows us to replace $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ with the much better behaved $\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$ (for which I'll just write $\ell^2$ from now on)

Additionally, as a corollary of the Hahn-Banach separation theorem and the fact $\ell^2$ is a Hilbert space, we have the following characterization of the closed convex hull:
$$x \in \overline{\operatorname{co}}(A) \iff \forall y \in \ell^2, \forall C \in \mathbb{R}, \Big(\big(\forall a \in A, \langle y, a\rangle \leq C\big) \implies \langle y, x\rangle \leq C\Big)$$

---

$(\Rightarrow)$: Suppose $x \in \ell^2$ is dominated.  Then we may choose $y \in \ell^2$ such that $\|y-a\|^2 < \|x-a\|^2$ for every $a \in A$.  Equivalently, $$\forall a \in A, \quad \langle x-y, a\rangle < \frac{\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2}2$$
If $x \in \overline{\mathrm{co}}(A)$, then by the above characterization, we'd have $$\langle x-y, x\rangle \leq \frac{\|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2}2$$
or equivalently $\|x-y\|^2 \leq 0$.  Then $y=x$, but this implies $x$ dominates $x$, which is a contradiction since $A\neq \emptyset$.  We conclude $x \not\in \overline{\mathrm{co}}(A)$.

---

$(\Leftarrow)$: Suppose $x \not\in \overline{\mathrm{co}}(A)$.  Then by the above characterization, there is some $y \in \ell^2$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\langle y, a\rangle \leq C$ for every $a \in A$ and $\langle y, x\rangle > C$.  Note $y\neq 0$ and define $$z = x-\left(\frac{\langle y,x \rangle-C}{\|y\|^2}\right)y.$$  Then for any $a \in A$,
$$\begin{align*}\|z-a\|^2-\|x-a\|^2 &= \left\|x-\left(\frac{\langle y,x \rangle-C}{\|y\|^2}\right)y-a\right\|^2 -\|x-a\|^2\ \\ &= \frac{\langle y,x\rangle - C}{\|y\|^2}\Big(2(\langle y,a \rangle-C)+(C-\langle y, x\rangle)\Big) \\ &< 0\end{align*}$$
so that $z$ dominates $x$.